# Tomcat SSL is very slow

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I have implemented SSL for Apache Tomcat8. It is very slow.
I followed the below article for implementing SSL.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

It takes lot of time to load the intial JSP, where i have all the css & javascript file includes.

Comment: That my be because of some of your resource might be taking too much time to load.. Did you analyzed the load time for all the resources in the network tab of browser console ??

Comment: Which OS is that? You don't tell

Comment: OS is linux. Yes all the css files and java script files are taking too long to download with SSL. Without ssl it downloads faster

Comment: can somebody tell me how i can improve the performance of tomcat8 SSL